# What does the intercept mean in a first-difference panel-data model (r-plm)?

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, plm

Using unbalanced panel-data (Unbalanced Panel: n=54, T=81-307, N=11138), I estimated both FE and FD models. My understanding that they are analogous for T>2 and if they produce different results, then it usually indicates a violation of the strict exogeneity assumption and therefore the FD is more consistent as it uses a weaker form of strict exogeneity than FE.

In `R`, using the package `plm`, the FD results show an estimate of the intercept (and in this case, it turns out to be significant). I am wondering what does the intercept mean and how to interpret its value?

Is it common/correct to force the intercept to zero? The results are a bit different when dropping the intercept but not by much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FD intercept is the linear time trend coefficient in levels:

$$y_{i,t+1}-y_{i,t}=\alpha_i-\alpha_i + \beta\cdot (x_{i,t+1}-x_{i,t})+\gamma \cdot (t+1-t)+\varepsilon_{i,t+1}-\varepsilon_{i,t}$$

You can add time to your FE spec to check if this is the culprit.

Also some good ideas in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86592/coefficient-sign-changes-in-fixed-effect-and-first-difference-estimation/87103#87103) on why $FD \ne FE$.